# How to get older posts from facebook page using facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

In my application I am taking posts from one facebook page like this

```
       dynamic pageData = client.Get("/" + pageId + "/Posts", new {
           access_token = _userAccesstoken
        });
```

But this only gives latest 25 posts.

How can I get older posts also ?

Comment: Use the next/previous link in the response

Comment: How do we use them ?

Comment: Do a request to them

Comment: I did it like this.  HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;    pageData = response.GetResponseStream();   but it gives stream & not data like first time.

Comment: You need to request to the next link of the paging object which will give you next 25 posts. and in this request you don't have to include access_token as access_token is already present in the next link url...